# How to List MasterPage Under Look and Feel MasterPage section in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have created a mastepage like SiteMaster.master. But i can not see it under Look Feel --> MasterPage section.

So what should i do?

Comment: How did you create it? Where did you put it?

Comment: I have used started masterpage on codeplex and it is under _catalogs/masterpage section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the deployment process, either via UI or farm/sandbox solution approaches the page is marked as a "publishing master page" content type.
In the UI, you should be able to select  [image]
In the Visual Studio 2010 approach, ensure that feature description file specifies the content type similar to this

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPageGallery" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" >
    <File Url="MyCustomLayout.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
       <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="4" />
       <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010105" />
    </File>
  </Module>
 </Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the feature *Publishing Infrastructure* in *Settings Site Collection* and
activate the feature *SharePoint Server Publishing Site Actions*.

Once you've done this, you see the options you need.

However, it's not under *Look and Feel*, but under the *Galleries* section.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature and SharePoint Server Publishing feature.

**To Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature**

- Go to site settings
- Under the Site Collection Administration
- Open Site collection features
- Scroll down and activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
  feature

**To Activate SharePoint Server Publishing feature**

- Got to site settings
- Under the Site Actions
- Open Manage site features
- Scroll down and activate SharePoint Server Publishing feature

Once that is done,

- Go to site settings
- Under the Look and Feel
- Select Master Page